# Posting JSON to php script server side fails

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, server-side

This is my `jquery` code:

```
var jsObj = {"user_id":5, "login":"hsm"};
var str_json = JSON.stringify(jsObj);
$.post("json_handler.php", str_json)
    .done(function(){
        alert('data sent successfully');
        window.location = "http://localhost/quranMapping/php/json_handler.php";
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('fail');
    });
```

NOTE: I made the redirection to check out where is the problem.

And this is my php code (`json_handler.php` file):

```
<?php

//create a DB connection
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","my_db");

$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = json_decode($input);

echo $result->user_id;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

As error have a look to the attached picture,

How can i correct such problem?

[image]

UPDATE: when I used `$input = $_POST['str_json']`  the error was `undefined index`

Comment: Do you get any errors from json_decode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Take the Post parameters as:
$input = $_POST['str_json'];

Comment: Which line ist line 17?

Comment: json_last_error(); gave me 0 as output so JSON_ERROR_NONE

Comment: did you dump the $result yet? I suspect it was null and the error raised when you access property user_id

Comment: can you print_r($input) and see what are you getting there?

Comment: print_r($input) ; did not give any output

Comment: Have a look to my update please

Comment: That's it. Since it return null or empty string, you should not access property user_id from it while you did.

Comment: What's with the extra `}` in your php?

Comment: @TelvinNguyen what shoul i do then?, I an newbye in php

Comment: I suggest for testing, simplify your php to just echo the json that was sent, then ensure that it matches what was sent using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The json_decode probably failed, returning a `NULL` value. Do `var_dump($result)` and `var_dump($input)` to see what you're getting from the client and from json_decode.

Comment: Same problem with it, bytheway, it is not who downvoted ur answer: )

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using

JS:

```
var jsObj = {"user_id":5, "login":"hsm"};
var str_json = JSON.stringify(jsObj);
$.post("json_handler.php", {"str_json" :str_json})
            .done(function(){
                alert('data sent successfully');
                window.location = "http://localhost/quranMapping/php/json_handler.php";
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('fail');
            });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//create a DB connection
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","my_db");

$input= $_POST['str_json']
$result = json_decode($input);

echo $result->user_id;
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `{` and `}`